# Simple embeddable MidiSynth for iOS?

Tags: iphone, midi, synthesizer

I have a guitar diagram app for Android that I am porting to iOS. Android has a embedded midi synthesizer (sonivox), so I can generate midi files and let Android handle the playback.

Is there a way to do this on iOS? Or are there very lightweight embeddable synths for iOS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update: My answer is out-of-dated.**  @lukebuehler's answer is much appropriate.

If you don't mind non-opensource solution, try [FMOD](http://www.fmod.org/index.php/download).  Being a commercial audio engine for games, fmod equips a simple MIDI synth.  I've tried the free evaluation version.  It plays GM MIDI files correctly on my iPhone 3G.

If what you want is not just a SMF file player, you want a full function GS/GM softsynth, which can response individual midi events in realtime.  You can try the [midisynth from CrimsonTech](http://www.crimsontech.jp/.).  Its license fee is fair.  Crimsontech provides several demo apps in  the appstore.  Besides, it also provides an evaluation SDK for free. You don't need to pay a penny for the license until you're really going to publish your app.

Comment: That's a nice one. I don't mind commercial software, only open standards are what I think is really important. Thanks for the headup, if you need something let me know, maybe I can help.

Comment: It looks like it's not able to stream midi events, that's quite a bummer. Upside is that it does support android and wp7. Hopefully for a single license.

Comment: Wow, you know a lot of stuff! Thanks for the pointer. I've contacted them.

Answer (score 21):

Since iOS 5 there's now the AUSampler audio unit for which you can load a sound bank (apple preset and soundfonts) and then control the sampler/synth via MIDI messages.

Seee this example app:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LoadPresetDemo/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html

It works great!

Comment: Thanks.  Your answer is more update-to-date than mine.  iOS 5.0 equips with a powerful sampler engine.  To play a GM/GS midifile, we just fed it with a soundfont containing rich set of instruments.  I found an [official technote][1] about how to load DLS2 soundfont file.  Anybody tried this? [1]:  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2283/_index.htmladd complete

Comment: Yep, I'm using sound fonts for my app (WorldScales) I'm loading a 100MB sf2 file, containing multiple sound banks, velocity layers and samples per patch. Beware though, there are some memory issues if you just keep switching the sound bank in the same sound font, i.e. memory is only cleared quickly if you load a different sound font file.

Comment: @lukebuehler, greetings... i'm in trouble. i have a mid file to play on iOS. problem is i don't have any idea on that. i never did audio related app but i am quit familiar with iOS development. could you please give me any guide i mean from  where to start. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think MIDI support in iOS 4.2 allows playback of MIDI data from the phone itself. It is merely for sending and receiving MIDI commands to other MIDI devices.

From the recent iOS 4.2 docs, it seems that you can use the MIDI support to send MIDI commands to other devices for playback. You can also receive commands from other devices and make changes to these commands, or to save it in a file. However I can't find any support to actually play MIDI file from the phone directly. Someone please correct me if I'm wrong (I wish I'm wrong!!).

Answer (score -3):

There is MIDI support in iOS 4.2. If it is the same as what OS X provides then trhere will also be a basic synth included. Check it out.

Comment: The MIDI support in 4.2 does not include a synth engine.

Comment: You might consider deleting this answer?