# Is there anyway read MIDI file to staff on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, midi

I just wanna know, is there some library or source can read midi file, parse it to staff and show it on iOS ?

Answer (score 2):

Check the MusicPlayer class. Combined with the AUSampler audio unit available since iOS 5.0 you can build a MIDI player quite easily. (The link is OS X, but it applies for iOS as well)

[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/ARoadmaptoCommonTasks/ARoadmaptoCommonTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003577-CH6-SW13)

About the sampler audio unit see [Simple embeddable MidiSynth for iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4240391/1597744)

Reference from [How to play MIDI on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2551568/1597744)